# How to fill a dictionary with all request headers

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

Im able to get request headers one by one when I have the header key name with this method

```
private string GetHeader(string Name)
{
    IEnumerable<string> headerValues;
    if (Request.Headers.TryGetValues(Name, out headerValues))
    {
        return headerValues.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    else { return ""; }
}
```

But what I really would like is to get all request headers and store them in a dictionary, something like this

```
Dictionary<string, string> ss = Request.Headers.ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value); 
//this doesn't work
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You can already enumerate all header values, because `Request.Headers` being of type `HttpRequestHeaders` is a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>>`.

So the Value is a `IEnumerable<string>` and your `Dictionary` has to change to

```
Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> ss 
       = Request.Headers.ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => a.Value);
```

or if you want to stick to the string value you can join the string enumeration.

```
Dictionary<string, string> ss 
       = Request.Headers.ToDictionary(a => a.Key, a => string.Join(";", a.Value));
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Of course it is a IEnuerable<string>..how could I missed that..Thanks for sharing

Comment: Can someone explain this answer? In simple terms. Why does this method (ToDictionary) need an expression? What is the Lambda expression doing?

Comment: @dsanchez you are converting an IEnumerable to a Dictionary. Request.Headers is an IEnumerable. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.todictionary?view=netframework-4.8